# How to restrict unpublish of a certain package version with verdaccio?

Tags: npm, package, verdaccio

I want to restrict the unpublishing of a package with a certain version number with Verdaccio.

I am aware of the feature called [Package Access](https://verdaccio.org/docs/en/packages).

I tried:

```
 '@scope/myPackage@1.0.0':
    access: $all
    publish: $authenticated
    unpublish:
```

this does not work.

Is there any other possibility to restrict the unpublishing of a certain version of a package published in verdaccio?

Comment: It's not good way, but it's working. set `unpublish: $None`. it's get with error and `unpblish` don't exec.